# Laptop charges on ubuntu but won't charge on windows 10

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, ubuntu-19.10

I am running dual boot with windows and ubuntu.
Laptop when booted into windows 10 it shows warning and plugged in and not charging.

when booted into ubuntu it charges.

Is there anything to do make it charge the battery in windows 10 as well

edit: It won't charge until the ubuntu is booted.

Comment: Wow man, im fascinated by your problem :)

Comment: check this out https://superuser.com/questions/1543858/laptop-not-charging-consistently-on-windows-but-does-on-ubuntu

Comment: @EbenezerIsaac Thank you i will try those

Comment: What kind of laptop (brand and model)?